# How to set environment variables on windows?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, environment-variables

I've forked a python project, which I always failed to run it. The author told "Set bash variables. Add export PYTHONPATH=path/to/blotus to ~/.profile or else."(blotus is a file he created before)
Then he ran on Ubuntu, but I use windows.
How can I set it on windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this at a command prompt immediately prior to starting Python:

```
set PYTHONPATH=path\to\blotus;%PYTHONPATH
```

This will set your Python path correctly before running your Python script.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your advice. Then I want to write this prompt in file that I can use it conveniently. What can I do?

Comment: You want to create a .cmd file with this command and probably also the command to invoke python for this job. Search the Internet for instructions on how to create and use .cmd files. There are many descriptions. If you found this answer useful, you can check the tick to the left of the text to show you have accepted this as your preferred answer.